# How to use firewall with ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic, firewall, apache-zookeeper

I have this ports configured in my **3 virtual machines** running `Zookeeper` and `ActiveMQ`.

```
root@mom3:~# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2881                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2888                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3888                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
61616                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
61617                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
2881 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
2888 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
3888 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
61616 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
61617 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

When I tried to start `ActiveMQ`, it gets a **random port** to use it:

```
 INFO | Master started: tcp://mom1.company.com:37649
 WARN | Store update waiting on 1 replica(s) to catch up to log position 0. 
 WARN | Store update waiting on 1 replica(s) to catch up to log position 0. 
 WARN | Store update waiting on 1 replica(s) to catch up to log position 0.
```

But when I disable my **firewall**, `ActiveMQ` start **normally**.

How can I use the same port every time, in order to create a new rule in my firewall ?

**EDIT**
Based on @Daniel's suggestion this is my configuration for `activemq.xml` file.

```
<persistenceAdapter>
    <replicatedLevelDB
        directory="${activemq.data}/leveldb"
        replicas="3"
        bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:0:61616"
        zkAddress="mom1.company.com:2881,mom2.company.com:2881,mom3.company.com:2881"
        zkPassword="password"
        zkPath="/activemq/leveldb-stores"
        hostname="mom3.company"
    />
</persistenceAdapter>

...
<transportConnectors>
    <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are writting about a zookeeper and I vaguelly rememeber this log line from when I was working with a master/slave replicated levelDB Setup I'll go ahead and assume you are also using one. If this is indeed the case then the port you are seeing there is the "bind" port the master starts up for clients to attach themselves to and start replicating data. This port can easily be configured in your brokers XML configuration using the bind parameter in the replicatedLevelDB section, for example

```
<broker brokerName="broker" ... >
  ...
  <persistenceAdapter>
    <replicatedLevelDB
      directory="activemq-data"
      replicas="3"
      bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:<myDesiredPort>"
      zkAddress="zoo1.example.org:2181,zoo2.example.org:2181,zoo3.example.org:2181"
      zkPassword="password"
      zkPath="/activemq/leveldb-stores"
      hostname="broker1.example.org"
      />
  </persistenceAdapter>
  ...
</broker>
```

will then always use "myDesiredPort" for the bind port. Since normally 61619 is the default port when this parameter is not set at all you probably already have this element configured right now, however with bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:0" which dynamically choses one. For more explanation and a full list of available parameters for the replicated levelDB see the [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html)

Hope this solves your Problem, if this is however not your setup please add your Broker configuration to your question this will make it easier to find the actual culprit without guessing.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your suggestion. I were right, that's my setup, 3 `zookeeper` server working with `activemq`. I tried the port `61619` and `61616` but I got `ERROR | Error in thread 'ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-1'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
 at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(InetSocketAddress.java:143)[:1.8.0_73]
`.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with the config, I think I spotted the problem. Just for completeness sake (this should not be the problem since you also tested `61619`) the bind port needs to use its own free port, in your config both the bind and openwire connector are using the same, this won't work since internally the bind does nothing too different from starting yet another connector with the given parameters. The real problem is however that you get one :0 too much in your config, right now you have `bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:0:61616"` please try it with `bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:61619"`.